# Undefined index with $_POST variable

Tags: php

with this code:

```
$tstUsername = getValue($_POST['tstUsername']);
$tstPassword = getValue($_POST['tstPassword']);

if ($tstUsername !== false && $tstPassword !== false) {
    echo "New string added to database!";
    haydayshops_mysql_query($conn,"INSERT INTO table_accounts (username, password) VALUES >('$tstUsername','".sha1($tstPassword)."')");
}
```

The code works fine, but when i put the error mode on, i see this nasty errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: tstUsername in ...
>
> Undefined index: checkPassword in ...

Comment: What is your question? Are you wondering [what undefined index means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836)?

Comment: var_dump($_POST)to make sure correct data is in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get these errors because you're trying to access to key of an array which doesn't exists. Here, you access to `$_POST['tstUsername']` but it doesn't seems to exists in the `$_POST` data. Same case with a key named `checkPassword` somewhere else in your code.

To avoid that, use [`isset()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if they are declared before trying to access to the value.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for that well explained answer. Yes it was exactly what i searched. Just didn't know how to use isset. Thanks :)